# uploading an array of images in ionic 3

Tags: php, ionic3

I can send an image to the server using this function, but I don't know how to send an array of these images yet, I'm taking the images with a cordova plugin.

```
getPicture(){
        const options: CameraOptions = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        }

        this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
            // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
            // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
            this.cameraData = imageData;
            this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            this.photos.push(this.base64Image);
            this.photos.reverse();


        }, (err) => {
            // Handle error
        });
    }
```

and I send to server with this

```
onSubmit() {
      let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: 'Carregando...',
      });
      loading.present();

      let url = "backend_cliente/api/api_upload_image.php";
      let postData = new FormData();
      postData.append('id', this.id);
      postData.append('file', this.base64Image);
      let data: Observable<any> = this.http.post(url, postData);
      data.subscribe((result) => {
          loading.dismissAll();
          alert(result);
      }, error1 => {
          loading.dismissAll();
          let mensagem = "Upload success";
          this.presentAlert(mensagem);
      });

  }
```

I tried it in several times, but I couldn't find a way to send an array of those images, because the function I'm using does not send string array.

and to receiving the shipment with this backend.

```
$data = ['result' => false];
$id = isset($_POST['id'])? $_POST['id'] : '';
$path = 'uploads/user-id-'.$id;
if(!file_exists($path )){
    mkdir("$path ", 0700);
}

$target_path = $path .'/'.$id.'.jpg';
$return = '';
if (isset($_POST['file'])) {

    $imageData = $_POST['file'];
    $imageData = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '',$imageData);
    $imageData = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', '',$imageData);
    $imageData = str_replace(' ', '+', $imageData);
    $imageData = base64_decode($imageData);

    file_put_contents($target_path, $imageData);   

}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

If there's better functions to send the array please, tell me

Comment: The post must be in English. Or delete it and post in https://pt.stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: The post needs to be in English but you don't need to translate variable names in your code. It could help others to understand your intent with English variable names though

Comment: I'll change it.

Comment: you could JSON.stringify your array of images (base64 strings), send this to your server as one mega large string, then on your PHP server side receive it and parse.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do I do that?

Comment: can anyone help?